# Passing parameter to a user defined function within a user defined function

Tags: r

I created a user defined function (gini_scorecard) which requires 4 parameters. The function would normally be called as follows:

```
gini_scorecard(development_data, swd_indicator, target, 1)
```

I want to now be able to call that function from within another function (predictive_vars). The predictive_vars function looks as follows:

```
predictive_vars <- function(dset, omit_list){

  for(i in names(dset)){
    if(!i %in% omit_list){
      temp01 <- dset %>% select(target, i)
      x <- gini_scorecard(temp01, i, target, 1)
      print(x)
    }
  }

}
```

In the following line (from the above function):

```
x <- gini_scorecard(temp01, i, target, 1)
```

I am unsure how to pass the second argument to the function. The function basically loops through all the variables in the dataframe passed (that are not in the omit_list list) and then I want to pass each variable to the function gini_scorecard. So 'i' represents the each eligible variable name in the dataframe. However I get the error Column i is unknown. I need to know how to convert that to the variable name in the dataframe?

Comment: Try using select(target, one_of(i))

Comment: Also, is target in your omit_list?

Comment: what is the expected behavior of `swd_indicator` ? it looks like you are feeding a name instead of an index.

Comment: Thanks all, I've decided to approach the problem from a different angle and use lapply. Thank you